# Pointer as parameter is null but after function pointer is not null

Tags: c, string, pointers

hello i have my funcion like:

```
void enterString(char *string) {

    string = (char*)malloc(15);

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s",string); //don't care about length of string now
}

int main() {
   char *my_string = NULL;
   enterString(my_string);

   printf("My string: %s\n",my_string); /* it's null but i want it to 
                                          show string i typed from 
                                           enterString */

   return 0;
}
```

I want to string from function show on string in main ... I don't know if you'll understand me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You are passing string by value. You neet to pass it by address :

```
void enterString(char **string) {

    *string = (char*)malloc(15);

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s",*string); //don't care about length of string now //you should!
}

int main() {
   char *my_string = NULL;
   enterString(&my_string);

   printf("My string: %s\n",my_string);

   free(my_string);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Care to argument the downvote ?...

Comment: Why would I have to argument the downvote?

Comment: So I can know what is wrong with my answer and improve it for everyone's gain. That's what this site is all about, right ?

Comment: I was asking that in hope that the person having cast the downvote would see it and answer accordingly. Don't take it personally if it wasn't you :p

Comment: On a second though; `scanf("%s",*string);` no!

Comment: You may want to double-check that comment, string is a char** ;)

Comment: My comment is perfectly fine; you missed the point. What happens when the user enters >15 characters?

Comment: Tears and damnation. But OP explicitly dismissed the case (that's his comment up there).

Comment: If you can't take the criticism don't ask for it.

Comment: Now I really don't see why you're upset... You're perfectly right about buffer overflowing, but OP stated that he didn't care for now, so I didn't bother and focused on his actual question. Feel free to comment on the Question where the problem is though :)

Comment: *Now I really don't see why you're upset...* ? I'm not. *Feel free to comment on the Question where the problem is though :)* I already did that.

Comment: All good then. Imperative comment added to OP's quoted code for completeness.